# why is email.js not picking up my post route for send-email?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, nodemailer

trying to get email.js to work with my application. I am using react.js on the front end. I am using a contact form to send me email when someone wants to connect or speak with me. just email, name, message and emailjs should send me a message.i keep receiving an error as shown below

POST http://localhost:3000/send-email 404 (Not Found)
handleFormSubmit @ Contact.jsx:14

heres my server.js

```
import express from 'express';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import cors from 'cors'; // Import the cors middleware

const app = express();

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config();

app.use(express.json());

// Use the cors middleware to allow requests from all origins
app.use(cors());

app.post('/send-email', async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;

  try {
    // Send email using emailjs
    await emailjs.send(
      's*****', // Replace with your service ID. hidden from public
      '****', // Replace with your template ID hidden from public
      { 
        from_name: name,
        reply_to: email,
        message: message
      },
      process.env.EMAILJS_USER_ID // Accessing emailjs user ID from environment variable
    );

    console.log('Email sent successfully');
    res.status(200).send('Email sent successfully');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error:",error)
    console.error('Error sending email:', error);
    
    res.status(500).send('Failed to send email');
  }
});

const PORT =  3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

heres my contac.jsx that holds my contact form

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import './contact.css';

const Contact = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [formError, setFormError] = useState("");

  const handleFormSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await fetch('/send-email', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ name, email, message }),
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        // Email sent successfully
        console.log('Email sent successfully');
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setMessage('');
        setFormError('');
      } else {
        const errorMessage = await response.text();
        setFormError(errorMessage || 'Failed to send email');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error sending email:', error);
      setFormError('Failed to send email');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="contact-container" id="Contact">
      <br />
      <h2 id="contact-me" className="bib">Let's Connect!</h2>
      <br />
      <form className="contact-form" onSubmit={handleFormSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="input-group">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Enter your name"
              value={name}
              onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="input-group">
            <input
              type="email"
              placeholder="Enter your email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <div className="txtA">
            <textarea
              placeholder="Type your message here"
              value={message}
              onChange={(event) => setMessage(event.target.value)}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        {formError && <p className="error-message">{formError}</p>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

Comment: `heres my server.js` ... does that also "serve" the web page? your web page posts to the same server as the page is loaded from. How are you running your server code?

Comment: Is your react web UI coming from that same host and port?  I ask because you're not specifying a host or port in your `fetch("/send-email", ...)` so it's going to go to the host/port that the web page came from.